# how to add a php inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

need some help on thi script

```
(function($) {
    var oldHide = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide;

    $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide = function() {
        if (this.options.trigger === "hover" && this.tip().is(":hover")) {
            var that = this;
            // try again after what would have been the delay
            setTimeout(function() {
                return that.hide.call(that, arguments);
            }, that.options.delay.hide);
            return;
        }
        oldHide.call(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: '#example',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () {
            return '<div class="box">here is some content</div>';
        },
        animation: false,
        delay: {
            hide: 1500
        }
    }).on({
        show: function () {
            console.log("shown");
        },
        hide: function () {
            console.log("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

this is a bootstrap popover and all I want is to add a php script inside

```
<div class=box><?php php_here(); ?></div>
```

because I need to output a wordpress script which is

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.?Have you tried it.?

Comment: no I can't because I don't know how to... :-(

Comment: How do you include the script via script tag or in the document itself?

Comment: I just want it to be like these <div class="box"><?php wp_nav_menu(); ?></div> that could output the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the file you try to write php in is a `.php` file or the server handles it like one, you can write php in it.
If this is a `.js` file, you might have to make it a `.php` file for the server to handle it correctly. But other than that, it should work as you want it to (there are ways to make the server handle javascript files as php files, but it might not be the best idea and its a bit more work than just renaming the js file).
If you change it to a `.php` file, you will want to send *content-type headers* with the type of `application/javascript` for the client to handle it correct.

Example:

*test.php*

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); ?>
alert('This is a .php file with javascript in it!');
```

*index.html*

```
<script src="test.php"></script>
//Should show an alert with "This is a .php file with javascript in it!" when opening index.html
```

*edit: added example*

Comment: Then its likely that your server handles it like a js file and php will not be handled correctly :)

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan Added a small example snippet showing how it works. Feel free to mark answer as correct if it gave you the information you needed!

Comment: I just happen to make the changes the way you said it, but now when I add <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?> it shows blanks but when I add <?php echo 'hello'; ?> it appears, is this something to do with wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
content: function () {
     return '<div class="box">'<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do this.. but you can move your javascript code into your php file (make a `<script>` tag) like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    var oldHide = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide;

    $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide = function() {
        if (this.options.trigger === "hover" && this.tip().is(":hover")) {
            var that = this;
            // try again after what would have been the delay
            setTimeout(function() {
                return that.hide.call(that, arguments);
            }, that.options.delay.hide);
            return;
        }
        oldHide.call(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: '#example',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () {
            return '<div class="box"><?php wp_nav_menu(); ?></div>';
        },
        animation: false,
        delay: {
            hide: 1500
        }
    }).on({
        show: function () {
            console.log("shown");
        },
        hide: function () {
            console.log("hidden");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

since php is server-side and javascript is client-side php will output what you wan't inside your javascript code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is this your expected one ?

```
content: function () {
     var wp_nav_menu ="<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>";
     return '<div class="box">'+wp_nav_menu+'</div>';
}
```

Comment: it does not output anything, it should show some lists I created in wordpress

Comment: but that is what Im trying to achieve

Comment: @Francis Alvin Tan, I have updated answer, can you check